# Spark parquet part number not sequential?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet, partition

I am using spark 3.0 to transform and sort data. Something which is worrying me is that I partition the data into 250 buckets, sort and then save. What I see in the output directory is typically 160 files with the file name starting with part-0000-** but the the number sequence is not consistent:

```
part-00000-f667f314-69f2-40d0-ba8a-b5b934650158-c000.gz.parquet
part-00002-f667f314-69f2-40d0-ba8a-b5b934650158-c000.gz.parquet
part-00005-f667f314-69f2-40d0-ba8a-b5b934650158-c000.gz.parquet
```

So what happened to parts 1, 3 and 4? This occurs throughout the files. Am I loosing data or is spark merging partitions for some reason? Code is like this:

```
 df = df.withColumn("bucket", F.abs(F.col("Id")) % F.lit(250))
 df = df.repartition(250,"bucket")
 df = df.sortWithinPartitions("id")
 df.write.option("compression", "gzip").parquet(outputPath)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to look at the distribution of the id column. In the first line you are doing a modulo if id with 250 which means that if the values 1, 3,4 etc are not present these ids would not get created. In the next step you are creating 250 partitions using `repartition` function. Some of these partitions might be empty.

You can try doing `df.repartition("bucket")` which will create atleast 200 partitions which is the default partition value. If you want to get no gaps then you can take a count and use repartition based on that.

Comment: The only difference between `df.repartition("bucket")` and `df.repartition(250, "bucket")` is that the former uses the default number of partitions, which is 200 unless configured otherwise. It doesn't change the fact that many partitions may be empty and there may (and most likely will) be gaps in the IDs. It is trivial to write test code.

Comment: Thanks. This does make sense. There are 2.5million unique IDs, and the ID is actually a 64bit hash. I would expect an even distribution but as you say, no guarantee that there are ids for each bucket, but easy for me to test

Comment: @HristoIliev - Yes you are correct, I forgot to mention about .write.partitionBy(COL) where the number of directories are created based on the unique values of COL.

Comment: @Jayadeep Jayaraman The reason I am not writing with partitions is that seems to destroy the sorting which is the most important part of the process.

Comment: Yes i saw your initial post and saw that you are writing to a non-partitioned table. if this answer was useful please do accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get partition IDs without gaps, you have to make sure that the number of partitions matches (or in general is less than or equal to) the number of unique partition key values:

```
df = df.withColumn("bucket", F.abs(F.col("Id")) % F.lit(250))
nkeys = df.select("bucket").distinct().count()
df = df.repartition(nkeys, "bucket")
df = df.sortWithinPartitions("id")
df.write.option("compression", "gzip").parquet(outputPath)
```

Also, note that the absence of certain partition IDs means those partitions are empty, which means your `id` values have a specific distribution. Depending on why you want to repartition your data, using the `id` column (`df.repartition(250, "id")`) is more likely to give you 250 partitions of almost equal size. This is because Spark actually uses the hash of the partition key and the hash function is more likely to transform the original distribution into a uniform one.

Comment: I appreciate your response. the Id is actually an xx64 (spark 3.0) hash anyway so I was hoping it would be uniform anyway. I will have to research why the distribution of 2.5million xx64 hashes is not so uniform.  I don;t actually care about the sequential file names, I was just worried about missing data. This has in turned made me question the id hashes.